# Magento block cache doesn't work in redis

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, redis

I'm using magento 1.14.02 EE on the two server instances with load balancer.

The FPC works fine in redis, but when I put block cache in redis it doesn't work.

If I'm using file system on each instance for block cache its working fine. What can cause this problem?

Comment: did you find the reason or any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In a 2 server architecture (and this is the first problem in a magento multi server setup), where is redis exactly located and how do you use it? In local.xml, in enterprise.xml? With or without colinmollenhour module? With or without Magento EE native Fpc?

Comment: Redis is located on 3 server, separated of this two. In local.xml, do we need to use in enterprise.xml? Whitout colinmollenhour, we using magento default. With native EE FPC.